# passing data to another view controller when tapping on annotation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I have an app that displays locations on map. I want to pass the data from the 1st view (MapViewController) to the another view (locationDetailViewController)

I have used the code below to pass the data and it takes me to another second view. however, it doesn't pass the mutable array to another view controller...

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{PlaceDetailViewController *det=[[PlaceDetailViewController alloc]init];
det.PlaceDetailMutableArray=PlaceMutableArray;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailView" sender:view];}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

On your SecondViewController.m, add the method (Don't forget to declare it on your SecondViewController.h too):

```
-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
NSMutableArray *PlaceDetailMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
PlaceDetailMutableArray = array;
}
```

And on the first ViewController, add the code below:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailView"]) {
 PlaceDetailViewController *det= segue.destinationViewController;
 [det setValue: PlaceMutableArray];
}
}
```

Finally, change the code of your example for:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailView" sender:view];
}
```

Comment: Ohh... on the method prepareForsegue, the line [det setValue: det.PlaceDetailMutableArray]; should be : [det setValue: PlaceMutableArray];

Comment: `-(void)setValue:(NSMutableArray*)array` is also incorrect. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you declare it on the SecondViewController.h? I tested and worked fine for me.

Comment: I didn't say that it is not working. I meant that this method does nothing.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Actually, if you put a breakpoint inside the method, you will see the objects of "array" is the same of "PlaceMutableArray". The method is there to do what the line "det.PlaceDetailMutableArray=PlaceMutableArray;" of the question would do.